# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException ... no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'

Tags: xml, spring, soap, namespaces

I have an *Eclipse-Maven-Spring* project and an `applicationcontext.xml` in it. This is:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

        <description>SoapClient1</description>

        <context:component-scan base-package="hu.bz.ikti.soap.test"/>
...
</beans>
```

When the xml is parsed i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 19 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context1.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
```

There is an error sign at the begining of the the later folloving `<http>` xml element:

```
    cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'http'. One of '{"http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, 
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/
 schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.
```

In the `xsi:schemaLocation` section i tried to add 
`http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd, spring-context-3.1.xsd, spring-context.xsd` but all the times i got the same error.

I have the following in my `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xsi:schemaLocation` isn't simply a list of schemas, it's a list of *pairs* of a namespace URI and its corresponding schema location.  So you need something more like

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
```

Comment: Hi, i have added `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd` but i still get the same error.

Comment: ... and i had already a `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"` element.

Comment: @SzZ did you fix up the security one too? The schemaLocation attribute should be alternating namespace and schema, your example in the question is "beansNS beansSchema securitySchema", i.e. it's missing the securityNS. And are you definitely using version 3.1 of all the spring libraries?

Comment: With these declarations: `<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
 xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">` and adding the `security:` prefixes and putting the user & pw tags in the factory bean the problen has resolved.